# Socket.io and Websockets Android 2.2

Tags: javascript, cordova, websocket, socket.io

I developed a app using cordova and used socket.io to connect my server app.
I've a problem because the android version 2.2 don't implement web sockets. 
i've been trying to use this plugin https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android/tree/2.x but i don't understand how implement this within socket.io,
for example i think so that this should to be work:

```
var socket;
if (typeof WebSocket === "function"){
  socket = io.connect();
} 
else {
   //socket.io should use the implementation socket using the plugin
   //sort of this: var ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
   //and pass this to socket.io of a some magical way
```

}

Comment: The WebSocket for Android polyfill you've linked to will supply a `WebSocket` constructor if the client doesn't already have a `WebSocket` constructor. As long as your socket.io connection happens after your `<script src="websocket.js">` tag, it should just work. Does it not?

Answer (score 0):

@user2593900,

you have a bigger problem. Android 2.2 is NOT supported by Cordova/Phonegap. You might be able to compile with Phonegap 3.x because the tools are still available and supported. Officially, Android 2.x, 3.x and 4.0 are deprecated and no longer supported.

From [Android Platform Guide: Requirements and Support](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/index.html)

> Cordova for Android requires the Android SDK which could be installed on OS X, Linux or Windows operation system. See the Android SDK's System Requirements.
>
> Cordova supports Android 4.0.x (starting with Android API level 14) and higher. As a general rule, Android versions become unsupported by Cordova as they dip below 5% on [Google's distribution dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Android versions earlier than API level 10, and the 3.x versions (Honeycomb, API levels 11-13) fall significantly below that 5% threshold.

Even the [Phonegap supported version 3.x](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) for the compiler says:

> Cordova supports Android 2.2, 2.3, and 4.x. As a general rule, platforms are deprecated as they dip below 5% on Google's distribution dashboard.